# ss.get.range('A1 Notation') FROM a CELL VALUE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function ABCDEF()
{
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SHEETNAME'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A17').setValue('ABCDEF');
}
```

> if possible I just need A1:A17 to be from a cell G14 with value = A1:A17

Comment: Do you mean you want the range A1:A17 of sheet SHEETNAME to be filled with the value for G14 (what sheet?)?

Comment: ah no, I want spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A17')  to be spreadsheet.getRange('G14')  G14 with value = A1:A17 so sscript will be spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A17')  then set value to abcdef

Comment: What will be the value of the cell `G14` ?

Comment: reason for this is G14 is , A1:A14 may extend or shorten with data.   so G14 counts the data G14 = "A1:A14"

Comment: you want to put all the data of A1:A14 to a single cell G14? If yes how that will be? comma separated for example? It would be better if you edit your question and provide an example (screenshot).

Comment: basically >>> spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A17')  << range needs to be updated based on G14 VALUE

Comment: So again to be clear, G14 contains the string "A1:A17"?  Then you want to get the values from that range?  And then what do want to do with them? Both are in sheet SHEETNAME?

Comment: https://ibb.co/3095xhm   < pic

Comment: hope the pic helps

Comment: Yes all are in the same sheet/workbook   then I want to setValue('ABCEF')  in the pic it was ABC only   set value will just put any text as I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would do it.

Get the range from G14, set the range equal to the value from G14 and then setValue()

```
function setRange() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange("G14").getValue();
    sheet.getRange(range).setValue("ABC");
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked. Thanks. sorry for the incorrect statements, but this worked flawless

Comment: Slight correction but no difference in results removed `range =` from `range = sheet.getRange(range)...`